# How can I pipe output from git log in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git

Reason: I want to compare two arbitrary different commits using a difftool. I know the hashes from a search and I don't want to copy these hashes, thus I am looking for a command that does something like

```
$ log_str=$(git log --all -S"new_tour <-" --pretty=format:"%h")
$ git difftool -t kdiff3 log_str[1] log_str[2] myfile.txt
```

- I would like to be able to address arbitrary indices - not always 1 and 2
- It would be great if the answer also gives a hint, how to figure out, what the structure of `log_str` is. Is it a character? An array of characters? A list? ... using the Bash.

I found some related help [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346557/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-git-push-command) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278502/accessing-array-index-variable-from-bash-shell-script-loop), but I can't make it work.
Now I do:

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h"
3f69dc7  
b8242c6  
01aa74f  
903c5aa  
069cfc5
```

and

```
$ git difftool -t kdiff3 3f69dc7 b8242c6 myfile.txt
```

Comment: You want `git diff HEAD~1 HEAD` ? That's the command you currently have. (Which is the same as `git show`)

Comment: @hek2mgl No, I want to compare two arbitrary different commits using a difftool and I don't want to copy the hashes...

Comment: Use `git rev-list` rather than `git log`: it's designed for scripting.

Comment: @torek: But `git rev-list -S"new_tour <-" --pretty=format:"%h"` does not work. Did I miss anything?

Comment: You had `--all` above; you'll need that, or `HEAD`, here (this is one significant difference from `git log`, which will assume `HEAD` if not given other revision specifiers to start from). Remove the `--pretty` argument entirely: rev-list's main job is to list revision hash IDs, so that's what it does by default.

Comment: @torek: Ok, `git rev-list --all` is working, but I can't select the relevant commits using `-S"new_tour <-"`. I also didn't find anything about `rev-list` + `pickaxe`. Sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Huh, apparently the -S and -G options *aren't* in `git rev-list`. This is a bit surprising. Generally the two commands take all each other's options (e.g., `git rev-list` accepts `--graph` and `--pretty`). Well, this is one case where you have to use `git log` after all. Sorry about that!

Comment: @torek :-) Then you could perhaps upvote the question ;-) Thanks for your great support!

Comment: @torek, may be this has something to do with the fact they are not about walking the graph but actually about diffing machinery (?)

Comment: @kostix: true, but in fact `git rev-list` still has to invoke the internal diff code for history simplification (though it gets to use the short-cut same-or-different-only path, which means it can leave out the xdiff library, perhaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a two step approach using a temporary file:

```
git log --all -S'SEARCH' --pretty=format:"%h" > tmp_out
git diff "$(sed -n '1p' tmp_out)" "$(sed -n '2p' tmp_out)" myfile.txt
rm tmp_out
```

sed is used to display line 1 and line 2 of the file.

---

With variables:

```
search="foo"
index_a="1"
index_b="2"
file="myfile.txt"
git log --all -S"${search}" --pretty=format:"%h" > tmp_out
git diff "$(sed -n "${index_a}p" tmp_out)" "$(sed -n "${index_b}p"  tmp_out)" "${file}"
rm tmp_out
```

in a bash function:

```
search_diff() {
    search="${1}"
    index_a="${2}"
    index_b="${3}"
    file="${4}"
    git log --all -S"${search}" --pretty=format:"%h" > tmp_out
    git diff "$(sed -n "${index_a}p" tmp_out)" "$(sed -n "${index_b}p" tmp_out)" "${file}"
    rm tmp_out
}

search_diff "foo" 2 3 myfile.txt
```

Comment: You are welcome but please don't my answer in a way that introduces syntax errors. Feel free to modify it according to your needs, but do not change it in place

Comment: I am sorry - what went wrong? I checked it on my laptop and everything worked. Otherwise I would not have changed anything...

Comment: which shell are you using?

Comment: Git bash for Windows

Comment: Not sure what's under the hood of that. In a normal bash a function definition using `def`, like `def foo()` is a syntax error. Besides that, I would generally not modify answers more than probably fixing a little syntax error. What you do on your computer is your thing, sure.